# Setting a default header for all requests in Angular except OPTIONS

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to include a default header in AngularJS for all requests except the Options request?

I know you could do this for patch, put, and post by  (for example for post):

`$http.defaults.headers.post['SomeHeader']='Something';`

But for everything except Options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an http interceptor to add your header on each request

```
app.config(['$provide', '$httpProvider', function ($provide, $httpProvider) {
    $provide.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$injector', function ($rootScope, $q, $injector) {
        return {
            // occurs on request
            request: function (config) {
                //Add your header to the request here
                return config;
            }
        };
    }]);
    $httpProvider.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
    }]);
 }]);
```

Comment: Yeah, that works, thanks. Just a quick comment though, the wrapped ```httpProvider.config...``` didn't work for me, only a direct ```$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');``` without the previous and next lines worked.

Comment: Between your app initialization `var app = angular.module('MyApp', [...]);` and your app running `app.run(...)`.